# *link* an entire folder of source files into a solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I've looked over some of the threads here, but I'm a bit confused by what appear to be contradictory answers.

I have a group of files that implement an XL-like grid in VB, the files are in a *directory* called "XL" (how original). I would like to include all of these in new projects *as links*. But I'd *really* like to put them in a folder, so I can have a single directory C:/develop/xl and then have that appear as a folder in VS.

I have seen some answers using ItemGroup, but others suggesting there is a way to do this using the VS UI. I'm on 2010, is there a simple way to do this, or do I have to edit the project manually?

Comment: Assuming this is C++ (don't make us guess).  Click the "Show all Files" toolbar button in the Solution Explorer window.  You'll see now see the folder, right-click it and select "Include in project".  If you want to make it look like a folder then add a filter and drag the files into it.

Comment: I have modified the original post to clarify: this is VB.net, and the "folder" is a directory on my HD. I want to include the directory, as a single object, in my project.